# Circular motion and momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

> I have to explain why there is a force pointing inwards in a circular trajectory (assume constant speed), but without relying on centripetal force argument.

Coordinate system is Cartesian coordinates with origin at the center of the circle. Usual y upwards and x positive to the right.

So I choose two arbitrary points in the circular path and know that momentum and velocity are tangent to the trajectory at any point.

From $\Delta \overrightarrow{p} = \overrightarrow{p_{f}} - \overrightarrow{p_{i}}$ I know that picking up any two points in the trajectory, the change in momentum can never point outwards the trajectory, it always points inwards.

From $\Delta \overrightarrow{p} = F_{net} \Delta t \iff \overrightarrow{F}_{net} = \frac{\Delta \overrightarrow{p}}{\Delta t}$ I can say that $\overrightarrow{F}_{net}$ must point in the same direction as $\Delta \overrightarrow{p}$.

Lastly, if I take $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ (not proving it, I'm going by intuition here), I can see that $\overrightarrow{F}_{net}$ becomes closer and closer to $\overrightarrow{F}_{net} \cdot \overrightarrow{v} = 0$ or $\overrightarrow{F}_{net} \cdot \overrightarrow{p} = 0$.

Is that a good explanation?

Comment: please explain your intuition argument, since everything just falls with it. I would use something similar like [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/171091/75518) and argue about $-\vec{r} \parallel \vec{a} = \frac{\vec{F}}{m}$

Comment: Can I ask why you can't use centripetal force to explain circular motion?

Comment: Because teacher is following a textbook that doesn't follow the usual way of studing kinematics first, dynamics later. I have to rely on the momentum principle.

Comment: well this is a dynamical problem. **use** dynamics to explain it.

Comment: First the force points outward. The way to understand it is by changing the referential. If you are in a non Galilean referential which is rotating the force that arises is just the inertial acceleration you actually have in the Galilean referential. It corresponds to taking the left hand side(accelerations) of the fundamental dynamic principle and passing it to the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your explanation's weak point lies with the intuitive jump you make by take the limit of $\Delta t$. You may need some mathematics or a diagram to support this intuition. For example, drawing a diagram showing the velocity vector and the small change in velocity vector, showing that in order to keep the magnitude of velocity constant, then the small change vector will have to be perpendicular to the velocity vector. There are a few other approaches you can use instead.

For example, you can think in terms of work. Work is equal to the force multiplied by the displacement travelled in the direction of the force. If work in done to a body, it will gain speed. However, in this case, the body moving in a circle does not gain speed. Therefore no work is done. For this to be true, the force applied must never be in the same direction as any displacement the body makes. This is true if the force is perpendicular to the trajectory of the body, i.e. towards the middle.

Another explanation you could give could use vectors. You can describe the position of a body in circular motion with the vector, with the origin in the centre of the circular path:

$$\vec r = (R \cos{\omega t} )\vec i + (R \sin{\omega t} )\vec j$$

Differentiate twice for the acceleration of the body:

$$\vec a = -(R\omega ^2 \cos{\omega t})\vec i - (R\omega ^2 \sin{\omega t})\vec j$$

$$\vec a = -\omega ^2 \vec r$$

$$\therefore \vec F = -m\omega ^2 \vec r$$

i.e. the direction of force is opposite that of the position vector. Because the position vector is radially outward, then the force vector must be radially inward.

Answer (score 0):

**Choosing any two points in the trajectory exposes one problem:** if the two points are along the width of the circle, both momentum vectors are going to be parallel and the difference is a vector that doesn't points inwards but is tangent to the trajectory. In case the two points are the same, but one is placed *"one lap"* later, both vectors are going to be the same and the difference is going to be null.

There is a slightly missconception in $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$. I was using that to explain why the vectors are orthogonal. While it's true for circular motion along a circunference, it's not for the orbit of planets. That operation is more closely related to explaining why there is an assumption that the force is constant. Because with $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, there is *"not enough time"* for a change in the magnitude of the force to be measured.

**Third problem:** I though that the question was the same as *"Two students proposed two vectors to represent the force acting upon the object at one point of the trajectory. One is an arrow pointing towards the center of the circle, the other is an arrow pointing in the opposite direction of the former"*. As I see now, explaining why the force cannot point outwards it's slightly easier than explaining why the vector must point to the center of the trajectory, or, in case of a planet, why the force points to the center of mass of the other massive object its orbiting.

**The answer given by the teacher was conceptualy much simpler:** Use $\overrightarrow{p}_{f} = \overrightarrow{p}_{i} + \overrightarrow{F} \Delta t$. If the vector with coordinates pointing outwards the center of the circle is applied, the curve would be in the opposite direction of the actual direction of the motion (if object is turning right and moving clockwise, force would make it turn left, which is absurd). Therefore, the vector pointing to the center of the trajectory is right and the other is wrong.